Do SATA 2.5" to USB adapters (enclosures) usually require drivers? (enclosures)
Do SATA 2.5" to USB adapters (enclosures) usually require drivers?
I'm trying to purchase one online, but I am uncertain if they usually function with GNU/Linux or merely only support Windows/Mac.

Like any device, yes, but I've never had one that didn't have built-in driver support from the OS (any OS). You can pretty much buy them without checking.

I have 2 and neither did other than work straight out of the box with Ubuntu.

Depending on power requirements make sure your USB port has enough power or adapter has external power. My first adapter worked great for a SATA SSD, but since only USB power would not spin up a HDD. Or I prefer SSD for external drives. I have two newer USB to M.2 adapters & use standard M.2 memory one is SSD and other NVMe.

USB storage drive enclosures are generally plug and play, and don't require installing any drivers in Ubuntu. USB power requirements for enclosures can vary, but they are generally sufficient for most storage devices. If your storage device is an SSD you have nothing to worry about. USB 3.0 and 3.1 ports typically provide more power than USB 2.0 ports.
Consult the USB storage drive enclosure's documentation or manufacturer's website to determine its power requirements.
I also question the wisdom of purchasing a USB storage device enclosure online because they are ridiculously cheap, so why not buy it at the nearest computer store instead and get a more effective guarantee?

Which is making me wonder: most 2.5 drives I have will need about 1A at peak (over 5V), so potentially exceeding 5W (max on USB 3.0 should be 4.5W). Yet I haven't had one shutting down (yet). There must be something wrong with what I'm saying, else wouldn't we constantly be living on the edge when using type-A connectors? I mean I guess the 1A from the spec is actually never / almost never needed? shrug

A typical 2.5" SSD draws around 2 to 4.5 watts at peak power consumption. max on USB 3.0 should be 4.5W, so USB 3.0 or USB 3.1's 4.5 watts should be sufficient to power a typical 2.5" SSD under most circumstances. If the SSD draws close to the maximum power available (4.5 watts) and the USB port can't consistently deliver that power, throttling may occur.

Ah yes, I was talking about mechanical drives. I have a relatively old 2.5" Toshiba in my hands that is rated 5V / 1A, exactly. I still use it to this day (in an enclosure) sometimes, yet not even tranferring huge files for an extended period of time has ever made it shut down (yet). I don't know, it's not important, I guess either USB 3 ports actually deliver more (out of spec) or these drives' are overrated / draw their maximum rating only for short amount of times.

USB-C ports can deliver up to 15 watts of power and you can connect a USB 2.0 or 3.0 device to a USB-C port using a simple USB-C to USB adapter cable.

Sure thing. But I've never done that :D so I was wondering what'd be the exact reason why I've never had a shutdown, as on paper the threshold could be easily exceeded
